# Python / tkinter: How to stop all the current running threads? (not asking for exiting, just stopping)

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, concurrent.futures

I've created an example code, so I could be more specific. Actual code is much more complex but kinda similar in functionality I want for stop button.
The code I can't figure out will go in line 25.

```
import threading
from tkinter import *
import time
import concurrent.futures

window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x300')

def main_fctn():
    for i in range(500):
        print(f'Counting {i}')
        time.sleep(2)


def count_threads():
    print(f'\n\nCurrently running threads: {threading.activeCount()}\n\n'.upper())


def starting_thread(arg=None):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as excecuter:
        thread_list = excecuter.submit(main_fctn)


def stop_threads():
    ### CODE TO STOP THE RUNNING THREADS
    pass


button1 = Button(window, text='Start Thread!')
button1.bind('<Button-1>', lambda j: threading.Thread(target=starting_thread).start())
button1.pack(pady=25)

button2 = Button(window, text='Stop Thread!')
button2.bind('<Button-1>', lambda j: threading.Thread(target=stop_threads).start())
button2.pack(pady=25)

button3 = Button(window, text='Count number of Threads')
button3.bind('<Button-1>', lambda j: threading.Thread(target=count_threads).start())
button3.pack(pady=25)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: 1. by line 25, I mean in stop_threads() function,
2. (not asking for exit, just stopping) in heading means: DO NOT WANT TO EXIT THE TKINTER WINDOW, but want to stop the running threads.

Comment: Simply way is to use `threading.Event()` object.  Create an instance of `threading.Event()` object, for example `event_obj = threading.Event()` in the global space, then in the for loop of `main_fctn()` check whether `event_obj.is_set()` returns True, if yes, break the for loop.  Call `event_obj.set()` inside `stop_threads()`.

Comment: @acw1668 doing event thing you said will stop further threads from creating, but it won't stop the currently running threads. **I want exact opposite thing**. _I don't want to stop further creating threads, but to stop the currently running threads._

Comment: You can call `event_obj.clear()` before the for loop.

Comment: @acw1668 Can you write the code what you trying to say, I can't get the point.

Comment: See [example code based on yours](https://pastebin.com/ikxWnk6F).

Comment: @acw1668 You can give this answer code in solution, It would help other people in future. btw Thanks I got the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is to use `threading.Event()` object:

- create an instance of `threading.Event()` in global space
- call `clear()` on the object before the for loop inside `main_fctn()`
- check whether the object is set using `is_set()` inside the for loop, if it is set, break the for loop
- call `set()` on the object inside `stop_threads()` if you want to stop the thread

Below is an example based on yours:

```py
import threading
from tkinter import *
import time
import concurrent.futures

window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x300')

# event object for stopping thread
event_obj = threading.Event()

def main_fctn():
    event_obj.clear() # clear the state
    for i in range(500):
        if event_obj.is_set():
            # event object is set, break the for loop
            break
        print(f'Counting {i}')
        time.sleep(2)
    print('done')

def count_threads():
    print(f'\n\nCurrently running threads: {threading.activeCount()}\n\n'.upper())


def starting_thread(arg=None):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as excecuter:
        thread_list = excecuter.submit(main_fctn)


def stop_threads():
    ### CODE TO STOP THE RUNNING THREADS
    event_obj.set()


button1 = Button(window, text='Start Thread!')
button1.bind('<Button-1>', lambda j: threading.Thread(target=starting_thread).start())
button1.pack(pady=25)

button2 = Button(window, text='Stop Thread!')
button2.bind('<Button-1>', lambda j: threading.Thread(target=stop_threads).start())
button2.pack(pady=25)

button3 = Button(window, text='Count number of Threads')
button3.bind('<Button-1>', lambda j: threading.Thread(target=count_threads).start())
button3.pack(pady=25)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This could be improved more, by passing the event_obj as an argument in the function, if using more than one thread.
I wonder how can one approach for threads not using 'for loop', but a function to extract data from an api? One can't use 'break' for such cases!

Comment: Different situations have different solutions.  Mine is just an example based on your posted code.